# JSON parse returns error

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, websocket

I'm using a websocket to make a vocabulary test. The program starts with returning a word, for example 'bonjour'. The user fills in the translation 'hello'. I want the word to be send to the javascript code in the form of a JSON object. In the PHP script, the array is send to the javascript file using json_encode. The array would look like this for example: `{"response":"bonjour"}`.

I'm trying to print the response with `array['response']`, but this returns `Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0`. I also tried `array.response`. I think it has to do with the fact that the JSON object is in plain-text. I tried to solve this using parseJSON, but it still returns `Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='UTF-8' />
    <style>
        input, textarea {border:1px solid #CCC;margin:0px;padding:0px}

        #body {max-width:800px;margin:auto}
        #log {width:100%;height:400px} 
        #message {width:100%;line-height:20px}
    </style>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="fancywebsocket.js"></script>
    <script>
        var Server;

        function log( text ) {
            $log = $('#log');
            //Add text to log
            $log.append(($log.val()?"\n":'')+text);
            //Autoscroll
            $log[0].scrollTop = $log[0].scrollHeight - $log[0].clientHeight;
        }

        function emptylog(){
            $("#log").html("");
        }

        function send( text ) {
            Server.send( 'message', text );
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            log('Connecting...');
            Server = new FancyWebSocket('ws://websocket.com/ws2/');
            emptylog();

            $('#message').keypress(function(e) {
                if ( e.keyCode == 13 && this.value ) {
                    log( 'You: ' + this.value );
                    send( this.value );

                    $(this).val('');
                }
            });

            //Let the user know we're connected
            Server.bind('open', function() {
                log( 'Connected' );
            });

            //OH NOES! Disconnection occurred.
            Server.bind('close', function( data ) {
                log( "Disconnected." );
            });

            //Log any messages sent from server
            Server.bind('message', function( payload ) {
                var array = jQuery.parseJSON(payload);
                log( array['response'] );
            });

            Server.connect();
        });
    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id='body'>
        <textarea id='log' name='log' readonly='readonly'></textarea><br/>
        <input type='text' id='message' name='message' />
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You need to parse `payload`, not `array`: `var array = jQuery.parseJSON(payload)`, and then access it as an object: `array.response`

Comment: @ishegg That was a mistake, but I used to have that in my code. It now returns this error: Unexpected token h in JSON at position 0.

Comment: What is the `payload`?

Comment: @ishegg The payload is the array that is returned from the PHP script. Its in the form of {"response":"bonjour","mistakes":"1"}.

Comment: Is that your *exact* response? Do `console.log(payload);` because `{"response":"bonjour","mistakes":"1"}` is valid JSON. Don't guess, please go and log it. By the error message, the first letter in the response is an "h" so it clearly isn't what you think it is

Comment: @ishegg Thanks I got it working. Turned out to be that everything was send as valid JSON, but only the first word was send as just plain-text "bonjour". That's why it gave an error. My bad.

Comment: Just curious but what about the 'h' Any insight as to where it came from?

Comment: @CliveMakamara I think it is because the user was asked for 'hello' and had to translate this to 'bonjour'. As I was accidentally sending this 'hello' plain-text and not as a JSON object, it probably got stuck on the first letter of hello, which is the h.

Comment: Awesome that clears things up, thanks